# Better to use a grounded list, or no?

Tags: c++, list, dynamic-variables, dynamic-list

I'm a csci student at Colorado Mesa University. The department head teaches a grounded method for linked lists:

```
struct nodeType
{
    int id;
    nodeType *link;
};

void createList(nodeType *&head, nodetype *&tail)
{
    head = new nodetype;
    tail = new nodetype;
    head->id=-1; //some initialize value
    head->link=tail;
    tail->link=NULL;
}

void insertList(nodeType *&head, nodeType *&tail)
{
    nodetype *knew,*prior, *next;
    knew = new nodetype;

    knew ->name = name

    prior = head;
    next = head->link;
    while(next != tail && knew->id > next->id)
    {
        prior = next;
        next = next->link;
    }

    prior->link = knew;
    knew->link = next;
}
```

She teaches this for obvious reasons. With the grounded head and tail, It's easier to insert from, as you call the above function, and then write a function to append all the data inside those two nodes, and it's slightly easier when writing your delete function, as you never delete head or tail, and thus it makes it harder to lose the list and create garbage.

My algorithms professor says that everywhere else that I encounter lists "in the real world," a non-grounded list would be better. Other languages, using the STL and on the internet, I wouldn't find list functions that implement a head and tail.

I just want to be prepared for programming in the actual real world, not what my professors think is the real world, so my question is this: Is it better to use one or the other, to use whichever I find easier, or to approach each problem with both in mind?

Thank you in advance for your time helping me resolve this feud.

Comment: Look at which one will help solve your problem better.  Many times you don't need to always know about the tail.  Other times you do.  Personally, i haven't used a linked list "in the real world" in several years -- so it's quite possible that you may never need either one.  :)

Comment: Programming in the real world. I've implemented a linked list once in 25 years of commercial coding, and that turned out to be a mistake. The answer is do it whichever way the one marking your assignment wants. Outside of la la land, you just grab an existing implemnentation that fits, or use a big hammer on it until it does. :(

Comment: For reference, though, (1) if you do use one, that "grounded" way looks rather odd to me.  (2) If it's C++, that function shouldn't exist.  The head/tail pointers should be hidden away in a class with a less hideous API.  And (3) if that's real code, it's wrong.  You'll end up never seeing your head or tail, because you're reassigning to the local `head` and `tail`, not the ones passed in; the caller never sees it change.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to pass by reference, fixed now. I also added my insert function so you can see how it was originally taught. 
So what it sounds like is that they're important while I'm in school and teachers are asking me to do stuff with them, but once I leave, it won't be nearly as important to know exactly every detail of them?

Comment: They're not even important while you're in school, except in the context of handing in exactly what you were told and learning next to nothing. Knowing how they work is a good thing, for any data structure, but the better part of what you see on a board or exercise prompt are things you'll want to *avoid* outside of la la land.

Comment: I think I understand. Obviously linked lists are important to understand for other data structures that I will learn, like trees for example, but as far as needing to write them myself in the field, I probably shouldn't, and I will seldom, if ever *have* to. Am I following?

Comment: Pretty much.  Just about any language/framework you use in the real world will already have some linked-list class (or an equivalent, if not better, data structure) built into it.  What you care about are the performance characteristics of a linked list and generally how it works, so you'll know when/if you come upon a situation that calls for one -- or if you see code that uses/implements one, you know what it's doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In "the real world", you will use a list that other programmers have designed, implemented, optimized, and tested, and you won't ever know whether it is "grounded", since that is just an implementation detail.

What's important to take away from your algorithms courses is:

- Performance characteristics.  Does a linked-list or vector have faster random-access?  Faster append?  Faster removal of the first element?  Using the right container is NOT premature optimization.
- Seeing enough different implementation styles so that if you ever have to step through your code with a debugger, you won't be royally confused.  If you saw the at-end-of-list test return true, but the next-node pointer isn't NULL, you'd probably be really confused if you'd never seen a "grounded" list implementation before.

Comment: IE I will most likely be using the STL list or one developed internally by wherever I work? Good to know, thanks! I'd vote up if I had the rep ^^;

Comment: @AndrewQ: Right.  Only a very small number of programmers work on library development and actually build these data structures.  Everyone else just uses them.

Comment: Thanks! Now I'll just approach this class like I approach math: do it their way in class, do it your way out of class.